# How to call web API URL in C# windows application and get response

Tags: c#

I am facing issue while calling API URL in my windows application . my code is as follow.

```
        var client1 = new RestClient("http://stagingapi.bulkmro.com/index.php/product/736387");
        var request1 = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request1.AddHeader("postman-token", "79dbc057-2279-0d13-9d98-484efbdce8da");
        request1.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

        //request1.AddHeader("authorization", "Api RjNOZmVxRFluSkY1VmxSOVBoaHVRM1lPTmZWeFFyRUI4ZVBWUWhMTA==");
        request1.AddHeader("authorization", "API '" + key + "'");
        IRestResponse response1 = client1.Execute(request1);
        string str222 = response1.ToString();
        string aa1 = response1.Content.ToString();
        var jss1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var dict1 = jss1.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(aa1);
        string key1 = dict1["value_id"];
```

but it is giving response as unauthorised. please suggest any answer.

Comment: Are you sure your token and/or API key is valid?
Whether or not your request will be autorised depends on what you put into the request, and how the API handles authorisation. what kind of API is this?

Comment: Why are you putting it as API + encrypted key value? Is it supposed to accept that?

Comment: Does the line: `//request1.AddHeader("authorization", "Api RjNOZmVxRFluSkY1VmxSOVBoaHVRM1lPTmZWeFFyRUI4ZVBWUWhMTA==");` working for you if uncommented?

Comment: This in API from which I want to GET data named "value_id". And the token no and API key is correct. I am am passing the API key which I have got from other API URL.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the API is using [Basic Access Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). Generally with BAA the header key is `Authorization` and the value is `Basic {base64 hash}`. In your example it looks like you are setting the value to `API {base64 hash}`.  Are you sure the API is expecting "API" in the value and not "Basic"?

Also, in your code:

`request1.AddHeader("authorization", "API '" + key + "'");`

You are actually sending single quotes around the hash. That generally should not be the case.  You are actually sending `API '{base64 hash}'`. You will need to remove the 'single quotes'. Like this:

`request1.AddHeader("authorization", "API " + key);`

If that doesn't work, try this:

`request1.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic " + key);`

Comment: Thanks Donald for your answer. I have tried above solution but still it is giving StatusCode as unauthorised in response1 instead of ok.

Comment: How are you generating the authorization key? It should be "username:password" string converted to base64.  I decoded that example hash you have and its another random hash, which is not normal for Basic Auth.

Answer (score 0):

try this,
request1.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic " + key);
..it gonna definately work